# Using underscore ("_") right after a variable in string templates in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, I'm trying to create a filename dynamically that includes a type and a date like this:

```
var filename = "ab_$type_$date.dat"
```

However, the second underscore in between the variables is causing a compile error:

> Kotlin: Unresolved reference: name_

I know I could concatenate the strings in the old fashion way:

```
var filename = "ab_" + type + "_$date.dat"
```

But I'm wondering if there is a different way to accomplish the same thing. Is there a way to escape special characters in string templates or any other way to get this to work?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just wrap your expressions in curly braces:

```
var filename = "ab_${type}_${date}.dat"
```